# Setting Background color in wordpress for bizway theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, azure, themes

I have a static website and I want to set the background color for the whole website to black,am using wordpress on windows azure,i have tried searching but no solution that could help me.

Any one who has a suggestion

the link to the site : http://hairimpressions.azurewebsites.net/

Thanks in advince

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `background-color` from `.header-container`, `.footer_bottom`, and `.slider-wrapper-container`.

Comment: you have to remove background color from other classes to apply background from body

Comment: ok let me try it again, but I did do that and the background color remained white.

Comment: pl apply and let me know , i will check on url from here

Comment: pl remove background and border from class .footer_bottom at line 531 and let me know

Comment: @Lutz Hom, I did remove background color from other classes,its still not working.

Comment: it almost looks proper..Do you want to remove borders too?

Comment: I will make it look proper...I have another question, Is it possible to add a second logo?

Comment: second logo means you want two images as logo?

Comment: you can place logo into your theme's header file after <div class="logo">

Comment: I don't have a theme's hearder file..only have theme option,themes page and theme function files

Comment: you can access from Appereance >> Editor

Comment: the is the hearder file,let try it there.

Comment: Pl take backup before continue

Comment: sorry to ask a lot of questions, how do I insert a image on wordpress or link to the image but I believe I have to upload the image first

Comment: yes upload image from media library and place below code <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><img src="path"></a>

Comment: ok image added, how to I set the image to be on right side of the header?

Comment: change path to your require path and apply  float: right; into <a href

Comment: Just one more last question how to remove borders from the slides?

Comment: you have used flexslider so to remove border, you need to remove border from class .flexslider

Answer (score 1):

You can set background color black, and remove all background which you have given to others classes 
.header-container, 
.slider-wrapper-container, 
.footer-wrapper, 
.footer_bottom {   background:none;}